# Should I check the answers to my questions?

Tags: discussion, support

Is it recommended to compile/run/check every answer (or the shortest for code-golf challenges) before accepting an answer?

Has people even posted code which looks good but doesn't work?

Comment: In general, if you see a large number of upvotes, it probably works. However, to be certain, you have to check it yourself. Don't forget about ideone.com .

Comment: I don't think there is a "best practice" on the matter. I tend to run the highly voted answer just to see them do their thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Has people even posted code which looks good but doesn't work?

Yes. In [Weirdest way to produce a stack overflow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21114/12205), [this answer (now deleted)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21130/12205) has provided an answer that nobody can reproduce.

Here's a screenshot for those without enough rep to view deleted answers:

[image: screenshot]